# Android- Screen linking not working

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

the app that I am creating has two buttons on the main screen, that then link to another screen. However, when I link to the other screeen, I do get the xml file to show up, but the class associated with that file does not seem to work. Like I have buttons on my other screen that do not do what they are supposed to (I have a back button that does not go back to the main page, and an image button that does not link to the video.xml screen).

Does anyone know the problem?

Main_Activity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {





    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    final Button videoNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton) ; 

    videoNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen2.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        //setContentView(R.layout.screen2xml);
        }
    });

    Button newsNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newsButton);
    newsNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen1.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        //setContentView(R.layout.screen2xml);
        }
    });
    }

    }
```

Screen 2.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class Screen2 extends Activity {




  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2xml);


    Button back = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    back.setBackgroundColor(5);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //finish();

            //Intent intent = new Intent(SImpleRssReader2Activity.this, rahul.SRR2.SimpleRssReader2.Screen1.class); 
        //startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    ImageButton vid1 = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    vid1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        //finish();

            //Intent intent = new Intent(SImpleRssReader2Activity.this, rahul.SRR2.SimpleRssReader2.Screen1.class); 
        //startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



    }
}
```

screen2xml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backButton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_button1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_button1" android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="@string/text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Video1.java

```
import java.io.File;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;

public class Video1 extends Activity {


    VideoView videoView;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
//Set video link (mp4 format )
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://vimeo.com/15615625");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);


     videoView.start();
     setContentView(R.layout.video);


    }
@SuppressLint("ParserError") @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wunapp.newsvideoapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen1">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen2">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".video">

        </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

I get this logcat error as well (after implementing the changes made in the comments)

07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wunapp.newsvideoapp/com.wunapp.newsvideoapp.Screen2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at com.wunapp.newsvideoapp.Screen2.onCreate(Screen2.java:30)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-16 15:46:01.259: E/AndroidRuntime(15421):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click videoNext, you're simply loading screen2's xml into MainActivity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen2xml);
```

If you want to load Screen2 activity, then you need to launch it with an intent like the one you have commented out.  That way the second activity will be shown and actually use the screen2's xml correctly.  Like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen2.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: 07-09 10:35:14.806: E/Handler(6745): Failed to handle callback; interface not implemented, callback:android.view.View$PerformClick@40da1ca8
07-09 10:35:14.806: E/Handler(6745): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method finishActivity(View) in the activity class com.wunapp.newsvideoapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'backButton'
07-09 10:35:14.806: E/Handler(6745):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3058)

Comment: When do u get the error?  What activity are you on, and what button are you pushing?

Comment: Try using "new View.OnClickListener" instead of "new OnClickListener"

Comment: Updated the MainActivity in the description so you can see what I have

Comment: you're also missing @Override over your oncreate method in Screen2

Comment: Still gives me an 'Unfortunately, NewsVideoApp has stopped' error

Comment: I dunno bud.  I've got almost the same code you have and no problems.  From your logcat it looks like there's a problem in your onCreate of your second activity, but I don't get the error here.  One other problem you have is you have ".video" in your manifest while your actual activity name is "Video1"

Comment: Really? Then that is strange, could you send me what you have? And maybe I can compare on my part.

Comment: Sure, let me know where to send it.

Comment: If you can, could you please send it to rahulsinha95@gmail.com? Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

instead of below code

```
videoNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

use `videoNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

it requires View.onclickListener.

and

instead of calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen2xml);
```

you should start a new Activity by startActivity(intent); method, and show this layout in this activity.
it is not recommanded to use setContentView more then one time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still does not solve my problem. The buttons in the next page do not work. They show up , but when you press them, they do not go to the page that they are supposed to go to.

Comment: read my answer one more time, in your whole code it is bad written . you need to call new View.onclickListner instead of new onclicklistner as suggested. you need to call StartActivity, instead of setcontentview. they are not going to work anyways.. apply my suggessions , then see what happening and edit ur question accordingly

Comment: I still have errors, could you check my logcat (edited in the question)?